# How to Produce Matrix Report in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, matrix

My original table contains data like this:

Original Table

[image]

I would want to produce a matrix report like this:

Matrix Report to Be Produced

[image]

The report would sum the salary according to the job and department number. How could write my code in MySQL to get this report? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Not sure what happened but those image links are not linking to an image. Which makes the question rather unanswerable

Comment: Images aren't generally useful anyway. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Looks like you haven't provided all the requisite information to achieve the target state from your image - where do you expect `ename` to be sourced from?

Comment: And those are definitely NOT at least not without a lot more explanation like for example where does the `ename` come from

Comment: And where do you get the number from in the Matrix that dont exist in the Original Table

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema, and handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Also, while I suppose the moment's passed, I really cannot see how that data set could produce that result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT job
    , sum( if( deptno = 10 ,sal,0) ) AS DEPT10
    , sum( if( deptno = 20 ,sal,0) ) AS DEPT20
    , sum( if( deptno = 30 ,sal,0) ) AS DEPT30
    , sum( if( deptno = 40 ,sal,0) ) AS DEPT40
FROM YourTable
Group BY job;
```

Comment: Oh, I would like to share another one I found from the Internet, the codes could also be: SELECT job, SUM(CASE WHEN deptno = 10 THEN sal ELSE NULL END) AS DEPT10 FROM emp GROUP BY job;                                                              Your codes are much better and more efficient. Thank you so much!